# Subset data based on conditions in R

Tags: r

I have multiple inputs like:

```
a <- x  y  z
     1  2  2
     2  3  2
     3  2  4
     4  2  4
     5  2  1

b <- c(1,2)
c <- c(2,3)
```

i want to subset this data based on a condition that a$x contains values greater than equal to b[i] and less than equal to c[i]

output should look like:

```
d <- x  y  z
     1  2  2
     2  3  2
     2  3  2
     3  2  4
```

i have tried this:

```
d = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=0))
names(d) = names(a)
for (i in 1:length(b){
d <- rbind(d,a[which(a$x>=b[i] &                                        a$x<=c[i]),])
}
```

Comment: So it should repeat the second row because it's in both groups? If so, maybe `do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y){a[a$x %in% seq(x, y), ]}, b, c))`. If not, `a[a$x %in% unlist(Map(seq, b, c)), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr::filter` function:

```
sub_list <- lapply(1:length(b), function(i) a %>% filter(x >= b[i] & x <= c[i]))
do.call(rbind, sub_list)

  x y z
1 1 2 2
2 2 3 2
3 2 3 2
4 3 2 4
```

Input data:

```
a <- structure(list(x = 1:5, y = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), z = c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

b <- c(1,2)
c <- c(2,3)
```

Comment: is it possible to have i number of data frames; first one containing x 1:2 and second one containing x 2:3

Comment: the `sub_list` object in the answer is a list containing `i` number of data frames. `sub_list[[1]]` will access the first data frame and `sub_list[[2]]` will access the second.

Comment: Base R adaptation - `Map(function(df,gt,lt) a[df >= gt & df <= lt,], a["x"], b, c)`